# How to add up true values from an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

How to write a function that will add up only true values? I've tried this, but it won't work:

```
const array1 = [true, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, true, 
false, false, true, true, true, true, false, false, true, true,];

const array2 = [];

function countSheeps(arrayOfSheep) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array1[i] === true) continue;

    return console.log(array2.push(countSheeps(array1)));
  }
}
```

As you can see I'm a begginer, so your explanation would meen a world to me.

Comment: Move the return out of the loop--it is causing your loop to end early

Comment: I did that, and this happened: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Comment: @vladika below code will loop through array1  if the condition match it will push value into array2

Comment: `console.log(array1.filter(Boolean).length);` --> `16`

Comment: This works just fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array1 = [true, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, true,
    false, false, true, true, true, true, false, false, true, true,];
const array2 = [];

for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array1[i] === true) {
        array2.push(array1[i]);
    }
}
console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to `countSheeps` to count and return the number of `true`s in the input.

There are a few problems in your original code.

1. Instead of counting `true` values, you skip over them (`if (array1[i] === true) continue`)
2. Instead of returning a final value, you return *the result of calling `console.log`* which returns `undefined` (`return console.log(...)`)
3. Your function exist after the first occurrence of `false` because you defined your `return` statement inside the `for` loop.

Similar to what you've already done, you could do:

```js
const sheep = [true, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, true, false, false, true, true, true, true, false, false, true, true];

function countSheep(arrayOfSheep) {
    let count = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < sheep.length; i++) {
        if (sheep[i] === true) count += 1;
    }
    return count
}

console.log(countSheep(sheep))

// -> 16
```

Inside the function I first initialise the variable `count` which holds the total amount of `true`s in the input array. This value get's updated after each iteration in the for loop that encounters the value `true`. Finally, after the for loop, the variable `count` is returned and logged to the console.

To solve the problem in one line you can do:

`console.log(sheep.filter(value => value === true).length)`

This first creates a copy of the array, filter the array so that it only contains the values `true` and finally counts the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

try this sir

```js
let array1 = [true, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, true, 
false, false, true, true, true, true, false, false, true, true,];
console.log("this first condtion",array1);
let search = true;
var count = array1.reduce(function(n, val) {
    return n + (val === search);
}, 0);
console.log("result", count)
```